# Conditional formatting in complex formulaa

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have two tables, table 1: A-S and table 2: U-Z.I want my conditions to apply totable 2 colum W and the row where U had identical entry as C.

This is my formula that I want it to meet the following conditions: `AND(COUNTIF($U:$U, $C1) > 0, $B1="BOO", $W1<>INDEX($D:D, MATCH($C1, $U:U, 0)))`

1. COUNTIF($U:$U, $C1) > 0 checks if the value in cell C1 (in column C) can be found at least once in column U.
2. $B1="BOO" ensures that the value in cell B1 (in column B) is "BOO"
3. $W1<>INDEX($D:D, MATCH($C1, $U:U, 0)) verifies that the value in cell W1 (in column W) is not equal to the corresponding value in column D (based on a match between C1 and column U).

I want the formula to highlight in column W the cells that are not identical with D given that they meet the aforementioned criteria. The highlighted cells I want them to be in column W and whichever row U is, the above formula highlights based on the row of C.

Comment: Put your formula in a separate cell, and try to get `TRUE`, `FALSE` values you want to base your formatting on. Once your formula is ok, you can use it in conditional formatting.

Comment: I do not get true or false when putting this formula in a cell I get N/A

Comment: NA will be treated as `FALSE`, in other words it won't trigger the conditional formatting.

Comment: When I apply this it gives me N/A in the entire column except one cell that says false

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.